# How to add new image element to html href link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I have a problem creating a new image element to this code here:

```
<a href="/sound-packs/" data-link-title="Sound Packs">Sound Packs</a>
```

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the HTML code because it belongs to a locked template of "jimdo". I can only insert CSS codes and javascript in the "head area". Is there a way to add an image element to this HTML code with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this using just javascript. Firstly you need to set the `window.onload` callback to a function. Within this function, you can then get the element you want to add the image to. Here I added the image to the element with the attribute `data-link-title` which is equal to `"Sound Packs"`.

Lastly, you can use `.innerHTML` on this element to add the HTML you want to add within this element. Here I added a `<br />` followed by an `<img>` tag:

```js
document.body.onload = function() {
  let soundPacks = document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Sound Packs"]');
  soundPacks.innerHTML += "<br /><img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a' alt='StackOverflow Logo'/>";
}
```

```html
<a href="/sound-packs/" data-link-title="Sound Packs">Sound Packs</a>
```

Comment: It actually works! Now I have only the problem that the picture appears only after the entire content is loaded. It then pops up very ugly :( Any ideas why? I'm a noob, sorry!

Comment: Perhaps using `document.body.onload` instead of `window.onload` might help a little. Unfortunately, the part you want to append the image to doesn't have a `class` or `id` and thus it takes a little time to append the item...

Comment: Seems that `document.body.onload` won't work with "Jimdo". `window.on.load` works but the image still appears after the content is loaded :( Right next to "Sound Packs" I have two more links I want to add an image to. Same Coder like "Sound Packs" with "data-link-title" "Apps" and "Comments. If I clone your code and do the same thing for "Apps" it show the image right to the "Apps" font but then the image for "Sound Packs" disappears! Do you know why?

Comment: Can you post your code in a jsfiddle or codepen so I can take a look at it

Comment: maybe it's easier for me to give you the adress of my website? Is there a possibility to send you the adress via pm?

Comment: @user10688226 unfortunately, StackOverflow doesn't have a pm system in place. From what I understand, I think all I'll need is a snippet of your js code. I've written up a version which works with multiple images, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcexrnjs/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184571/discussion-between-nick-parsons-and-user10688226).